# Stopping Grails from adding .JSP file excentions

Tags: grails, groovy

I am working on a project. We are migrating code to Grails. The problem is the person who wrote the file saved it as .html and we are not trying to mess with it just to add a nice spring login. However, I cannot get Grails to show the .html. I changed URLMapping to start there and it just changes it to index.html.jsp. I changed Config.groovy and removed the html part from grails.mimes.types. That didn't work. So, I changed grails.mime.file.extensions to false. Still, nothing. It keeps adding .jsp. Any solutions?

Comment: where are you putting this html file?

Comment: Did you try to put it into web-app directory?

Comment: And do what? use a  <%@ include file> in the view to render it?

Comment: And do nothing. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple rename it's extension to .gsp. Test it - add to urlMapping file line `"/test(view:'yourFileName')"`, run the app and go to this link.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to make any processing, it's just a static html file, or just a static file. You should put it into `web-app` dir, for example as

```
web-app/login.html
```

and it will be accessible from the browser as `http://localhost:8080/%YOUR APP%/login.html`